# Avoiding N+1 queries in Ruby on Rails with nested associations and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on a podcast player and wish to display a list of recently updated feeds, along with details of the play time remaining for the most recently published entry.

So the view looks something like:

```
@feeds.each do |f|
  puts @feed.rss_image.url
  puts @feed.most_recent_entry.published_at
  if play = @feed.most_recent_entry.most_recent_play_by(@user)
    puts play.remaining
  end
end
```

My models are as follows:

```
class Feed < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :rss_image, as: :rss_imageable
  has_many :entries, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :most_recent_entry, -> { order(published_at: :desc) }, class_name: "Entry"
  has_many :plays, dependent: :destroy
end

class Entry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :feed, touch: true
  has_many :plays, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :most_recent_play, -> { order(updated_at: :desc) }, class_name: "Play"

  def most_recent_play_by(user)
    plays.by(user).order(updated_at: :desc).first
  end
end

class Play < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :feed
  belongs_to :user

  scope :by, ->(user) { where(user: user) }

  def self.most_recent_by(user)
    by(user).order(updated_at: :desc).first
  end
end
```

My query is:

```
@feeds = Feed
  .joins(:entries)
  .includes(:rss_image, most_recent_entry: :most_recent_play)
  .where(most_recent_entry: {plays: {user: @user}})
  .group(:id)
  .order("max(entries.published_at) DESC")
  .limit(10)
```

But this errors with:

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "rss_images.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Is it possible to achieve this without N+1 queries?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [Bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), it helps to reduce the number of queries and eliminate n+1. In this case it should suggest you how to modify you query, eg. adding .includes(:entries) ....

Comment: Thanks. The only recommendations it is giving me is `includes(:rss_image, :most_recent_entry)`, which I'm already doing.